# Powercounting in String Frame?

Tags: string-theory

if I consider the low energy effective action of type IIB string theory in the string frame, i.e. with an $e^\phi$ prefactor, is it possible to do standard powercounting with this action? I.e. how do I read of the mass dimensions of the fields? Do I need to transform it to Einstein frame first? In other words, how do I do powercounting for the action

$$S=\int d^{26}x e^{\phi}\Big(R+(\partial\phi)^2-\frac{1}{12}H^2\Big)$$

with $H_{ijk}=3\partial_{[i}b_{jk]}$. $\phi$ is a dilaton, $b$ a Kalb-Ramond field and $R$ the Ricci scalar. What's the mass dimension of the exponential? And than the other fields? Should'nt there be Newton's constant somewhere, too?

Thanks

Comment: Exponential has no mass dimension, and you forgot a global term $\sim \frac{1}{l_s^{24}}$, see

Comment: See this [ref](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string/seven.pdf), page 168

Comment: Some tricks: since $\phi$ lives in the exponential, it must be dimensionless. Another way to see it: the Ricci scalar has dimension 2 (contains two derivatives), so the terms $(\partial \phi)^2$ and $H^2$ must also have dimension two, which again implies that $\phi$ is dimensionless (and $[H] = 1$).